# Make everything work as of buttons in items of menu

Tags: java, android

I have a viewpager with different buttons in it; it is working good when it up to buttons.

But, I want to change those buttons into items and it is not working. I am confused where to put .setadapter, ..r.id.viewpager?

if there were buttons I'd directly set onclickListener it and do whatever i want in onCreate but in case of items we should go outside onCreate so I am very confused about what to do next.

this is my activity:

```java
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String toalPages ;


    Bitmap bitmap;
    private int[] imageUrls = new int[]{
            R.drawable.opt3,
            R.drawable.oq,
            R.drawable.oqqqq,
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        ActionMenuView bottomBar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
        Menu bottomMenu = bottomBar.getMenu();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bottom_view_pager, bottomMenu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.next) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true); //getItem(+1) for next
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.prev) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }
}
```

and, I've 2 `onOtionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` in same activity how can I make them work?

Answer (score 0):

The  onOptionsItemSelected not work because   you need to override method in your activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
}
```

try it .

Comment: Im not getting you could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Dibas the method not work onOptionsItemSelected in your activity because the activity you don't know what the menu is attach with you so you need attach menu it's contains the items by using the method :  onCreateOptionsMenu and put the your menu nested 'R.menu.menu_home' for example : R.meun.base_menu .